# Flexbox wrap text containing other element like input anchors

Tags: css, flexbox

Give a flexbox row containing text and input controls, how to break the sentence taking as much space as available, align the flexbox in a normal inline flow.

The reason for using flexbox is to align vertically, and the gap property.

[image: output]

```html
<script>
  window.console.warn=()=>{}
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
 
<main class="min-h-screen bg-gray-300">
  <div class="w-full mx-auto p-10  ">
    <section class="grid gap-4 bg-white rounded-md drop-shadow-md p-8">
      <header class="font-lg font-bold">No Flex Wrap</header>
      <div class="flex gap-2 items-center text-slate-500">
        <div class="whitespace-nowrap">Please add</div>
        <input class="px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 block w-48 rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1" placeholder="you@example.com" />
        <div class="whitespace-nowrap break-all">a long text to which should wrap instead of pushed to new line</div>
        <input class="px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 block w-48 rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1" placeholder="address" />
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="grid gap-4 bg-white rounded-md drop-shadow-md p-8 mt-8">
      <header class="font-lg font-bold">Flex wrap</header>
      <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2 items-center text-slate-500">
        <div class="">Please add</div>
        <input class="px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 block w-48 rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1" placeholder="you@example.com" />
        <div class=" ">a long text to which should wrap instead of pushed to new line</div>
        <input class="px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 block w-48 rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1" placeholder="address" />
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

**CodePen Playground**

*https://codepen.io/foobarxp32/pen/RwMKaJd?editors=1100*

Comment: You want the text to stay on the same line but also wrap at the edge of the container, an then the last input at the end, right?

Comment: @Zohini yeah, inline can't be used as it messes up y margin, width, and y axis center alignment

Comment: Nothing wraps text like that other than inline

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: flex` from the parent and assign `display: inline` to the children. I had to use the `!important` to this property in codepen because the it was not working on `input` element. Also remove `white-space: nowrap` from all elements.

```
parent > * {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: can it done with flex or inline-block

Comment: Flexbox and inline-block does not allow an element to break into pieces.

Comment: inline will mess up the vertical alingment and width of input boxes(i'm using material input library for input)

Comment: Try demoing the issues using the codepen so that they can be addressed.